Jitsi Installation via Docker: WebSocket Connection Could Not Be Established
I recently tried to install Jitsi along with Jibri and a whiteboard on my GCP instance using Docker. The system has 8 cores and 16 GB of RAM(Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)) . Despite following the installation steps, I encountered an issue where the console shows the error:
[modules/statistics/statistics.js] <Mi.sendAnalyticsAndLog>:  
{"type":"operational","action":"connection.failed","attributes":{"error_type":"connection.otherError",
"error_message":"The WebSocket connection could not be established or was disconnected.",
"suspend_time":0,"time_since_last_success":null}}

After some time, a message appears stating

Below is my .env file configuration:
ENABLE_AUTH=1
AUTH_TYPE=jwt
JWT_APP_ID=app_id
JWT_APP_SECRET=app_secret
JWT_AUTH_TYPE=token
JWT_TOKEN_AUTH_MODULE=token_verification
JWT_ALLOW_EMPTY=0


# Directory where all configuration will be stored
CONFIG=~/.jitsi-meet-cfg

# Exposed HTTP port
HTTP_PORT=80

# Exposed HTTPS port
HTTPS_PORT=443

# System time zone
TZ=UTC
DISABLE_HTTPS=0
PUBLIC_URL="https://meet.jitsi.mydomain.com"
JVB_ADVERTISE_IPS=172.17.0.1
ENABLE_HTTP_REDIRECT=1
ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT=1
LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN=meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com 

# Name your etherpad instance!
ETHERPAD_TITLE="Video Chat"

# The default text of a pad
ETHERPAD_DEFAULT_PAD_TEXT="Welcome to Web Chat!\n\n"

# Name of the skin for etherpad
ETHERPAD_SKIN_NAME=colibris

# Skin variants for etherpad
ETHERPAD_SKIN_VARIANTS="super-light-toolbar super-light-editor light-background full-width-editor"

 # XMPP password for Jicofo client connections
 JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD=my generated pass

 # XMPP password for Jigasi MUC client connections
 JIGASI_XMPP_PASSWORD=my generated pass

 # XMPP recorder password for Jibri client connections
 JIBRI_RECORDER_PASSWORD=my generated pass

 # XMPP password for Jibri client connections
 JIBRI_XMPP_PASSWORD=my generated pass



  # Container restart policy
  RESTART_POLICY=unless-stopped
  # Jitsi image version (useful for local development)
  JITSI_IMAGE_VERSION=latest


  ETHERPAD_URL_BASE=http://etherpad.meet.jitsi:9001

  #Whiteboard Config
  WHITEBOARD_COLLAB_SERVER_PUBLIC_URL=https://whiteboard.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com

  #XMPP config
  XMPP_DOMAIN=meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
  XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN=auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
  XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN=internal-muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
  XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE=https://xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:5280
  XMPP_MUC_DOMAIN=muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
  ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET=1
  XMPP_MODULES=info.alert
  XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_MODULES=info.alert
  XMPP_RECORDER_DOMAIN=recorder.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
  XMPP_SERVER=xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com

  #stun servers

  #JIBRI CONFIG
  ENABLE_RECORDING=1
  JIBRI_RECORDER_USER=recorder
  JIBRI_RECORDING_DIR=/config/recordings
  JIBRI_FINALIZE_RECORDING_SCRIPT_PATH=/config/finalize.sh
  JIBRI_XMPP_USER=jibri

  JIBRI_BREWERY_MUC=jibribrewery
  JIBRI_STRIP_DOMAIN_JID=muc
  DISPLAY=:0=
  JIBRI_LOGS_DIR=/config/logs


  #JVB CONFIG
  JVB_AUTH_USER=jvb
  JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD=generated pass
  JVB_BREWERY_MUC=jvbbrewery
  JVB_STUN_SERVERS=<stun servers>

Prosody Logs:
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 focus.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:tls                             info     Certificates loaded
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:muc_domain_mapper                 info     Loading mod_muc_domain_mapper for host conferenceduration.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com!
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 conferenceduration.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:conference_duration_component  info Starting conference duration timer for muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 conferenceduration.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:tls                            info Certificates loaded
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:muc_domain_mapper                             info Loading mod_muc_domain_mapper for host recorder.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com!
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 recorder.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:tls                                      info Certificates loaded
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:muc_domain_mapper                             info Loading mod_muc_domain_mapper for host auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com!
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:19 auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:tls                                          info Certificates loaded
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:20 c2s55ef24d50b10                                                           info Client connected
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:21 c2s55ef24d50b10                                                           info Stream encrypted (TLSv1.3 with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:21 c2s55ef24d50b10                                                           info Authenticated as focus@auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:21 auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:limits_exception                             info Setting stanza size limits for focus@auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com to 10485760
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:22 c2s55ef24dbb6d0                                                           info Client connected
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:23 c2s55ef24dbb6d0                                                           info Stream encrypted (TLSv1.3 with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:23 c2s55ef24dbb6d0                                                           info Authenticated as jvb@auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:23 auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com:limits_exception                             info Setting stanza size limits for jvb@auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com to 10485760
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:25 c2s55ef24e29bf0                                                           info Client connected
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:25 c2s55ef24e29bf0                                                           info Stream encrypted (TLSv1.3 with TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
prosody-1  | 2024-07-26 16:55:25 c2s55ef24e29bf0                                                           info Authenticated as jibri@auth.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com

JVB Logs:
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.101 INFO: [1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart: Started Server@3db64bd4{STARTING}[11.0.21,sto=0] @6154ms
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.110 INFO: [1] MainKt.main#139: Starting private http server
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.129 INFO: [30] [hostname=xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com id=shard0] MucClient$2.connected#321: Connected.
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.129 INFO: [30] [hostname=xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com id=shard0] MucClient.lambda$getConnectAndLoginCallable$9#646: Logging in.
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.528 INFO: [1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart: jetty-11.0.21; built: 2024-05-14T03:19:28.958Z; git: 996cd61addad9cb033e0e3eba6fa3f0fa3dc270d; jvm 17.0.11+9-Debian-1deb12u1
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.761 INFO: [30] [hostname=xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com id=shard0] MucClient$2.authenticated#327: Authenticated, b=false
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:23.914 INFO: [30] [hostname=xmpp.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com id=shard0] MucClient$MucWrapper.join#771: Joined MUC: jvbbrewery@internal-muc.meet.jitsi.mydomain.com
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:24.812 WARNING: [1] org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.WadlFeature.configure: JAXBContext implementation could not be found. WADL feature is disabled.
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.185 WARNING: [1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.checkProviderRuntime: A provider org.jitsi.rest.Health registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.jitsi.rest.Health will be ignored. 
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.191 WARNING: [1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.checkProviderRuntime: A provider org.jitsi.rest.Version registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.jitsi.rest.Version will be ignored. 
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.197 WARNING: [1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.checkProviderRuntime: A provider org.jitsi.rest.prometheus.Prometheus registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider org.jitsi.rest.prometheus.Prometheus will be ignored. 
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.767 INFO: [1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6661d8c0{/,null,AVAILABLE}
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.769 INFO: [1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart: Started ServerConnector@5d1b9c3d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
jvb-1  | JVB 2024-07-26 16:55:25.770 INFO: [1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart: Started Server@396e6d9{STARTING}[11.0.21,sto=0] @8823ms

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this WS Connection issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
